# Why is the "this" keyword being used here?

Tags: java, event-handling, this

I'm new to Java. I found the following code snippet online while trying to understand Java's Event Handling mechanism. This code is taken from [JavaTpoint.com](http://www.javatpoint.com/event-handling-in-java)

```
import java.awt.*;  
import java.awt.event.*;  

class AEvent extends Frame implements ActionListener{  
TextField tf;  
AEvent(){  

tf=new TextField();  
tf.setBounds(60,50,170,20);  

Button b=new Button("click me");  
b.setBounds(100,120,80,30);  

b.addActionListener(this);  

add(b);add(tf);  

setSize(300,300);  
setLayout(null);  
setVisible(true);  

}  

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){  
tf.setText("Welcome");  
}  

public static void main(String args[]){  
new AEvent();  
}  
}
```

I have studied the various uses of "this" keyword in Java & have realized that it is used to pass the current object as an argument to the following method.

```
b.addActionListener(this);
```

However, what I don't understand is why there is a need to pass the object as an argument. What exactly is the program accomplishing by doing that?

I'm sorry if such questions already exist or if it sounds like a stupid question, but I'm just a beginner.

Thank you for your time!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to format your code when you post - it's *much* easier for everyone to read properly-indented code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class `AEvent` implements the `ActionListener` Interface and must implement the `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` method. 
So the class is a action listener itself.

In the constructor of the class a `Button` is defined and it wants to know what should happen if it is clicked. So you register a `ActionListener` which "listens"to the click.

As Listener you register `this`, because `this` is a valid listener. 
So if you click the button, it will seach for an added listener and calls the `actionPerformed` method. And that method happens to be in the same class.

You do this to avoid making many listener classes. 
But you can also define a new class implementing the interface and register an instance of the new class as listener.

Answer (score 1):

The class which implements the ActionListener interface, is 'this' class.

The addActionListener method takes a parameter of type ActionListener p, because 'this' class implements the ActionListener interface, the word 'this' can be used as an argument.

EDIT: It is accomplishing access to the actionPerformed method defined in this class.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils It is accomplishing access to the actionPerformed method defined in this class?

Answer (score 0):

When your button is clicked, the event is dispatched to the ActionListener that you specify. Here it is the instance of AEvent creating the button.

Answer (score 0):

Here this refers to class AEvent and because it implements **`ActionListener`** interface, that is why you are able to pass it as an argument. So it is an instance of AEvent

**However, what I don't understand is why there is a need to pass the object as an argument. What exactly is the program accomplishing by doing that?**

> Its the api that want you to provide an object which actually implements actionListener interface. And because AEvent does so by implementing actionPerformed method, you have passed this.
>   When you click your button or lets say trigger onclick event on the button, you can respond to it by implementing actionPerformed method. Either by further processing or showing any kind of messages.`

For more details, you should refer to [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

Answer (score 0):

"this" in Java refers to current instance. you can register the button to listen to user action with this code
b.addActionListener(this);

Where "b" is the object of Button and "this" is the Object of "ActionListener", in your example you are able to use "this", since your class is implementing the Interface "ActionListener"